# adding new PropertyChanged event to Form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, enums, inotifypropertychanged

```
    public partial class FrmEditSiteParticulars : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    public enum EntryTypes
    {
        Undefined,
        Site,
        Particular
    }

    private EntryTypes _EntryType;

    private EntryTypes EntryType { 
        get{return _EntryType;}
        set
        {
            if (value != _EntryType)
            {
                _EntryType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EntryType");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler EntryTypeChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = EntryTypeChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
.
.
.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
.
.
.
```

and I added

```
this.EntryTypeChanged += new 
     System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(this.EntryType_Changed);
```

inside `InitializeComponent` method..

Now when I open the Designer 
[image]

I clicked `Ignore and Continue`, it worked fine..

Now when I close and open the solution again, the eventHandler code I put in the `InitializeComponent` is missing..

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
```

There's the answer. Put your code in the constructor, below `InitializeComponent();`.

Comment: Your observation and approach towards solution is superb.. :)